# A view that can be moved and resized on android

Tags: android, resize, imageview, view-hierarchy

I'm making an app that should allow users to dynamically put ImageViews into existence, move them where they please, resize them and mess around with the layer stacking of said views.

The layer stacking I do have some rough idea of how to implement, tutorials are still welcome tho.

What I'm drawing blanks on is the resizable ImageView and had no luck trying to find either tutorials for that or github projects that offers such a thing.

I'm not 100% new to android programing, but some more advanced concepts still fly over my head high enough for me to be unable to properly reverse engineer couple "close but no cigar" classes I've found.

To give a visual interpretation of what I'm looking for, here's WayCooler, which does exactly what I need to do.

[image: WayCooler]

I'm rather sure I'm just failing to use the proper search words to find what I need, but if someone can point me in the right direction, I'll really appreciate it.